# Подойдет ли strapi для создания веб-проектов на Vue.js?

Tags: веб-программирование, vue.js, strapi

Есть ли у кого опыт работы со [strapi](http://strapi.io)? Интересуюсь подойдет ли он для простого создания веб-проектов на Vue.js? Опыта работы с API нет, но в Strapi и админ панель привязать можно. Получается это некий бэкэнд базис сайта же? Инфы по нему просто мало

Answer (score 0):

Да, конечно можно использовать, Strapi по сути просто реализует RestAPI, управлять которым можно через панель Strapi и да, для не сложных вещей хорошо подходит, т.к. вы реализуете правильную концепцию работы web-приложения.